# transient-mark-mode, pre-command-hook and with-current-buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm writing a minor mode (a keylogger) which stores detailed (timestamp, etc.) info about every command through a custom `pre-command-hook`.  But it doesn't work nicely with `transient-mark-mode` - specifically setting another buffer as active in the hook through `with-current-buffer` seems to stuff up the active region in the buffer I'm actually working on.

I have `transient-mark-mode` on, and when I `C-SPC` and move the point around, the active region is highlight as normal, and all the active-region commands work.  However, once I've added my logging hook which contains a call to `with-current-buffer`, then I can't highlight regions anymore.

Minimal broken example:

```
(defun test-pre-command-hook ()
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*test-buffer*")
    (insert "foo")))

(add-hook 'pre-command-hook 'test-pre-command-hook)
```

at this point, `C-h v transient-mark-mode` is still `t` but visually the active region isn't highlighted, and commands which work on the active region e.g. `comment-dwim` don't work.

Once I remove the hook, things are hunky dory again.

```
(remove-hook 'pre-command-hook 'test-pre-command-hook)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem does not seem related to `with-current-buffer`... same problem happens with `set-buffer`.  Also, same problem happens evaluating the example code outside the pre-command-hook (but I am not sure why this is happening)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not `set-buffer` or `with-current-buffer` but `insert` which sets `deactivate-mark` globally.
The usual workaround is to let-bind `deactivate-mark` around your pre-command-hook:

```
(defun test-pre-command-hook ()
  (let (deactivate-mark)
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "test-buffer")
      (insert "foo"))))
```

Note that this problem should hopefully be fixed in the current Emacs trunk (i.e. what will probably become Emacs-24.5).